# Execution Timed Out(1600ms) How can I optimize this codewars kata to run faster?

Tags: java

I'm working on a simple kata on Codewars in which I was tasked with creating two methods: one that takes in a string to decrypt and an int to determine how many times the string gets encrypted, and another method that takes in an encrypted string and and int to determine how many times the string needs to be decrypted.

The encrypt method works by taking all of the characters at odd indices in a string and concatenating them then concatenating all of the characters at even indices.

Here's an example:

```java
//returns "hsi  etTi sats!"
System.out.println(encrypt("This is a test!",1));
//returns "This is a test!"
System.out.println(decrypt(encrypt("This is a test!",1),1));
```

I finally found a solution that works in IntelliJ, but when I tried it in the kata it timed out. I was hoping to get some suggestions on ways to make my code more efficient.

```java
public static String encrypt(final String text, final int n) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int i;
    String newText = text;
    int numTimes = 0;
    while(numTimes!= n) {
        for (i = 0; i < newText.length(); ++i) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(newText.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < newText.length(); ++i) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(newText.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        ++numTimes;
        newText = stringBuilder.toString();
        stringBuilder.setLength(0);
    }


    return newText;
}
// decrypt method divides encryptedText into two sides and uses a for loop to iterate 
//through both sides and add each chars to a StringBuilder
public static String decrypt(final String encryptedText, final int n) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int i;
    int numTimes = 0;
    String decryptedText = encryptedText;

    while(numTimes != n) {
        String left = decryptedText.substring(0, (decryptedText.length() / 2));
        String right = decryptedText.substring((decryptedText.length() / 2));
        for (i = 0; i < left.length(); ++i) {
            stringBuilder.append(right.charAt(i));
            stringBuilder.append(left.charAt(i));
        }
        if (right.length() != left.length()) {
            stringBuilder.append(right.charAt(right.length() - 1));
        }
        decryptedText = stringBuilder.toString();
        stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        ++numTimes;
    }
    return decryptedText;
}
```

[Screenshot of original kata problem, if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kus8B.png)

Comment: Inside your while-loop, you're doing 2 **full** for-loops over `newText.length()` even though every second index in both loops is a "do nothing". Remember that even though the standard for-loop is `for(int i = 0;i < foo; i++)` all 3 of those parts can be customized.

Comment: @Kayaman  would something like `for (i = 1; i < newText.length(); i += 2)`  and `for (i = 0; i < newText.length(); i += 2)` work better as the loops do not go through every character in `newText` but instead only focuses on every other char?

Comment: There you go, that halves the complexity of that part. Whether that's enough is a different thing, but a basic rule is "fastest code is the code that never runs", so avoiding half of `i % 2` checks can't definitely be a bad idea.